# How to suggest a good place for a line break to breqn?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, breqn

I have a long equation that I want to automatically break over multiple lines using breqn. The equation is:

```
 C_{\bm{r},\bm{V}} = \max \left\lbrace c: \forall S\subseteq \{1,\dots,N\}, 
      c \leq I(\bm{V}_{S^C};X) + \sum_{m\in S} r_m - I(V_m) \right\rbrace
```

It will break properly if I put it in `dmath` and tack on an extra relation (like `\leq`) to the beginning of the second line, to suggest to breqn that it is a good place to add a line break if needed.

Obviously the extra symbol is meaningless so I should also make it not print. So instead I could do something like `\mathrel{\phantom{.}}` to create an invisible relation character and break the line.

The problem is that in practice, adding a predefined relation character like `\leq` makes `dmath` break the equation properly, but adding a `\mathrel{\phantom{.}}` does not break it at all.

---

Here is a MWE demonstrating this behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{dmath}[compact]
  C_{\bm{r},\bm{V}} = \max \left\lbrace {c:\forall S\subseteq \{1,\dots,N\},}
      \leq {c \leq I(\bm{V}_{S^C};X) + \sum_{m\in S} r_m - I(V_m)} \right\rbrace
\end{dmath}

\begin{dmath}[compact]
  C_{\bm{r},\bm{V}} = \max \left\lbrace {c:\forall S\subseteq \{1,\dots,N\},}
      \mathrel{\phantom{.}} {c \leq I(\bm{V}_{S^C};X) + \sum_{m\in S} r_m - I(V_m)}\right\rbrace
\end{dmath}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

The equation in the first column is broken properly with the `\leq`, but the one in the second column is not broken at all with the invisible relation.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is duplicate to this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357904/how-do-i-suggest-good-places-for-line-breaks-to-breqn-dmath

Comment: My mistake, posted twice.

Comment: Your setup seems a bit conflicted: If you already know where a decent line-breaking opportunity is located, why not employ something like a `multline` environment right away? Incidentally, the outer curly braces produced by `breqn` are much too large if you specify them as `\left\lbrace` and `\right\rbrace`; might as well write them as `\biggl\lbrace` and `\biggr\rbrace` right from beginning.

Comment: The file containing this piece of text is `\input` into multiple documents (one being a 2-column document, the other being a wide 1-column document) so unless the breaking is automatic, the content will look good in one and bad in the other